# Regex to catpure all words from from a text file separated by white space

Tags: regex

I have only some basic understanding of Regex. My intention is to capture every single word in the word document and for this purpose I designed this regex. My word document consist of digits written like Rs.1,00,000/- and it also contains decimals written like 57.58. It will also contain reference to files written like F.No.245/12-445/235 not separated by white space.

It is almost successful with the following Regex

```
(Rs\.)?((\d{1,2}[\,])?)+(\d{3}\/\-)|([']?[\(]?[A-Za-z0-9][']?[-]?[?]?[!]?[:]?[-]?[.]?[/]?[\.]?[\(]?[\)]?[\(]?[\)]?[\/]?)+
```

In order to capture the words I cut it from word document and paste into a text file which is subject then read by a C# program. My problem is that I never want the period or dot that appears at the end of words. It is all okay if end word is followed by exclamation mark or question mark. When I tested it it captured 13150 words from the text file while the word documents shows that there are 13,158 words.

Comment: What don't you use a regex that just matches non whitespace chars, such as `\S+`?

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much. I tweaked your reply. I just now experimented with ([A-z0-9,./-:-;?]+) and found it very good. I will examine it in more detail later as I am very ill with fever now.

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much. I tweaked your reply. I just now experimented with ([']?[A-z0-9,./-:-;?']+) and found it very good. I will examine it in more detail later as I am very ill with fever now. Unnikrishnan

Answer (score 0):

You want non-blank characters, followed either by whitespace or "F.No.":

```
\S*?(?=\s|(F\.No\.))
```

Comment: Oh.Great. Expect for a minor hitch. But that is nothing compared to the simplicity of your regex. I chcecked it. In my original post I have not said that I wanted to capture \S. I wanted to capture each word separately. I used your expression and then from the result obtained deleted all those \S cases. It perfectly talled with the final result I had obtained with my own Regex ([']?[A-z0-9,.’'/-:-;?'&!?\.\*\(\)\/\']+). But your Regex showed me the beauty of your language and expertise with Regex. Thank you very much to Bohemian and sp00m. Unnikrishnan

Comment: The simplest Regex for this purpose definitely was of sp00m. At last I tried it like \b(\S+)\b. It capttured almost all words from the test file. Thank you very much. Unnikrishnan.

Comment: But \b\S\b matches two words from "foo-bar". \b matches word-to-nonword, not word-to-whitespace

Comment: Thank you for telling me the inside of things. But ultimately everything for me boils down to separating the words as MS Word count. foo-bar counts as one word in MS Word. That is what I wanted. Thank you Bohemian. But I have still not succeeded in capturing endash and emdash created with Alt 0150 and Alt + 0151 All of my tricks failed.